# Angular js and browser back button history issue

Tags: angularjs, state, browser-history

I am facing a problem in my application where I am in view A then I navigate to view B and after that to view C.
Expected behavior when I press back button is C->B->A , but the actual behavior is C->B-C->B etc, basically it enter infinite loop and keeps adding to the history the current state.

I tried to check documentations and search the same issue unfortunately i was not able to find anything about it